# Changing column titles with a "." period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I imported data into Rails using a .sql file, to discover that most of the column titles have a period "." in them. This is clearly an issue and after attempting to run a migration that changes the column names, the period is still throwing it off. Any workarounds to speak of?

```
class FixColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
          change_table :my_table do |t|
               t.rename :p1.address, :'p1_address'
          end
     end
end
```

Comment: To understand why the above doesn't work, consider the fact that the expression `:p1.to_s` returns the string `"p1"`. The expression `:p1.address` will raise a NoMethodError (which, by the way, you should have included in your question) because `:p1` is a Symbol, and Symbols do not respond to a method named `address`. As Simone illustrates below, a Symbol with special characters (or spaces) in it must be enclosed in quotation marks, i.e. `:"p1.address"` or `:'p1.address'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a string:

```
t.rename "p1.address", "p1_address"
```

The following syntax is also valid:

```
t.rename :"p1.address", :"p1_address"
```